# MS-SQL Server 2008 size limitation on data

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I recently discovered that MS-SQL Server 2008 imposes an upper limit of 8000 bytes for a column (for character data).
I need to store data that occusionally could surpass this limit.
Is there a way to do this?
The data are character strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**varchar(max)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) or [**nvarchar(max)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).  These have a storage limit of 2^31-1 bytes.

Comment: @squillman:But here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx does not make such a distinction.

Comment: @user76678 Yes it does.  On that page see the lines that say **Bytes per varchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, text, or image column** and  **Characters per ntext or nvarchar(max) column** under Database Engine objects.

Comment: @squillman:May be it is my missunderstanding;what is the difference with `Bytes per short string column`?

Comment: @user76678 Also, are you using SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2?  Whereas this particular item is not different between the two, they are different versions.

Comment: @user76678 **Bytes per short string** is for the non `max` flavor of varchar and nvarchar.  That is, (n)varchar can go up to 8000 characters (ie- varchar(8000) / nvarchar(8000))  When you use (n)varchar(max) that changes the game.

Comment: @squillam:Mainly R2.